# C# socket thinks it's connected

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to create a server/client program but when my internet (server host) disconnects the clients thinks they still connected but they are not (ofcourse). When I close the server just normally by closing the process it works perfectly fine. The code I use to check if the connection is still alive:

```
 if (_clientSocket != null)
                {
                    if (firstConnect != true)
                    {
                        if (!_clientSocket.Connected)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Not connected");
                            LoopConnect();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
```

I've also tried to replace `if (!_clientSocket.Connected)` with `if (!SocketConnected(_clientSocket)` with this method:

```
static bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
        {
            bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
            bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
            if (part1 && part2)
                return false;
            else
                return true;
        }
```

but both go to the else and print Connected. I am clueless why this happends only when my internet disconnects and not when I close the server normally. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try searching. You can't detect a non-graceful disconnect until you try to write.

Comment: As an aside, you can simplify some of your boolean logic here. In your first code snippet: could simply be `if (!firstConnect)` and in your SocketConnection method: `return !part1 || !part2, rather than your if-else construct. It's long winded and unnecessary. Let the boolean logic do the work for you :)